# How to retrieve data within a Map in java using findBy spring repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

I need help in creating a findBy spring query for the following scenario:
I have a JSON document with the following structure:

```
"data":{
"key1":"value1",
"key2":"value2"
}
```

In model, I have this"data" as a Map like,

```
Map<String, Object> data;
public Map<String, Object> getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Map<String, Object> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
```

Now, I want to get the value2 from data using spring repository. I'm using couchbase for DB.

Any help would be really appreciable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you attempt in any way to do this? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/couchbase/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/#datatypes

Comment: I wan to use findBy to get the data. For instance, if I have key2 outside the map data, I can query it as findByKey2(). But in my case, it is inside data. How to frame findBy query to get that data?

Comment: I don't think you can. Why not retrieve the object and then just return key2 from that object, using a method that calls the repository?

Comment: Thanks @aepure. I found the answer in the link which you shared. By using N1QL based querying.

Comment: Great to hear that! You should post your answer for the community :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Entity
 public class Obj{
  private Integer id;
  private String name;
   //getter and setter
 }

 @Controller
 public class ControllerClass{
    @Autowired
    private ObjService objService;

    @GetMapping("/getObjectById/{id}") 
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Obj> getMapDetails(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        Map<String, Obj> map = new HashMap<>();     
        map.put("data",objService.findById(id));    
        /*here you can able to N of times 
          Ex: map.put("data",service2.findById(id));
          and etc...
        */
        return map;
   }
 }

 @Service
 public Class ObjService{
    public Obj findById(Integer id){
       //logic
    }
 }

 your Response will be like below:
 {"data":{
        "id":1,
        "name":"value2"
   }
 }
```